# Keras 2.2.4 fit_generator problem . Value error, Problem in inputting values to the input layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running Keras multi_gpu model. My model takes 2 inputs. one input is given by the Imagedatagenerator and other input is generated through a function inside the model. please have a look at the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers import ReLU,MaxPooling2D,ZeroPadding2D,BatchNormalization,Dense,Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Lambda, Concatenate, Add

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras import backend as K
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
from tqdm import *
# import skimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing
# import pydot

########### Make Log directory #####################################
cwd=os.getcwd()

log_dir = cwd+'/log_dir/Relation_net_logs'
if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
    os.makedirs(log_dir)

tensorboard_logsdir = log_dir+"/tensorboard_logdir"
if not os.path.exists(tensorboard_logsdir):
    os.makedirs(tensorboard_logsdir)

######### Make Network##############################################




def ConvolutionNetworks(kernel_size=3, stride_size=2):
    def conv(model):
        model = Conv2D(24, (9, 9), strides=(stride_size, stride_size),activation='relu',input_shape=(100, 100, 3), data_format='channels_last')(model)
        model = BatchNormalization()(model)
        model = Conv2D(24, (7, 7), strides=(stride_size, stride_size),activation='relu')(model)
        model = BatchNormalization()(model)
        model = Conv2D(24, (kernel_size, kernel_size), strides=(stride_size, stride_size),activation='relu')(model)
        model = BatchNormalization()(model)
        model = Conv2D(24, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1),activation='relu')(model)
        model = BatchNormalization()(model)
        return model
    return conv

######### Compute Relations #######

def compute_relations(objects):

    def get_top_dim_1(t):
        return t[:, 0, :, :]

    def get_all_but_top_dim_1(t):
        return t[:, 1:, :, :]

    def get_top_dim_2(t):
        return t[:, 0, :]

    def get_all_but_top_dim2(t):
        return t[:, 1:, :]

    slice_top_dim_1 = Lambda(get_top_dim_1)
    slice_all_but_top_dim_1 = Lambda(get_all_but_top_dim_1)
    slice_top_dim_2 = Lambda(get_top_dim_2)
    slice_all_but_top_dim2 = Lambda(get_all_but_top_dim2)

    d = K.int_shape(objects)[2]
    features = []
    for i in range(d): #This loop extracts top layer of the feature map 
        features1 = slice_top_dim_1(objects)
        objects = slice_all_but_top_dim_1(objects)
        for j in range(d):  #This loop extract each object from the "top layer" extracted in the previous loop and append it in variable "features"
            features2 = slice_top_dim_2(features1)
            features1 = slice_all_but_top_dim2(features1)
            features.append(features2)

    relations = []
    concat = Concatenate()
    for feature1 in features:
        for feature2 in features:
            relations.append(concat([feature1, feature2]))



    return relations

############## f_theta ############################

def f_theta():
    def f(model):
        model = Dense(256,activation='relu')(model)
#         model = Activation('relu')(model)
        model = Dense(256,activation='relu')(model)
#         model = Activation('relu')(model)
#         model = Dropout(0.5)(model)
        model = Dense(256,activation='relu')(model)
#         model = Activation('relu')(model)
        model = Dense(256,activation='relu')(model)
#         model = Activation('relu')(model)
        return model
    return f


################# Relation module and tag building #########################################

from keras.utils import plot_model

def g_th(layers):
    def f(model):
        for n in range(len(layers)):
            model = layers[n](model)
        return model
    return f

def stack_layer(layers):
    def f(x):
        for k in range(len(layers)):
            x = layers[k](x)
        return x
    return f

def g_theta(h_unit=256, layers=4):
    r = []
    for k in range(layers):
        r.append(Dense(h_unit))
        r.append(Activation('relu'))
    return g_th(r)

def get_MLP():
    return g_th()

def RelationNetworks(objects):
    g_t = g_theta()
    relations = compute_relations(objects)
    print("length of relations={}".format(len(relations)))
    g_all = []
    for r in tqdm(relations):
        g_all.append(g_t(r)) #send each relation to g_t and append to a list for easy summation.

    print("relation computed")
    combined_relation = Add()(g_all)

    print("relation combined")

    f_out = f_theta()(combined_relation)

    print("relation went through f_theta")
    return f_out

def build_tag(conv):
    d = K.int_shape(conv)[2]
    tag = np.zeros((d,d,2))
    print("tagging in process")
    for i in range(d):
        for j in range(d):
            tag[i,j,0] = float(int(i%d))/(d-1)*2-1
            tag[i,j,1] = float(int(j%d))/(d-1)*2-1
    tag = K.variable(tag)
    tag = K.expand_dims(tag, axis=0)
    batch_size = K.shape(conv)[0]
    tag = K.tile(tag, [batch_size,1,1,1])
    print("tagging done")
    return Input(tensor=tag)


################################# Build Model ###################################################################################

visual_scene = Input((100, 100, 3))
# visual_question = Input((11,))
visual_conv = ConvolutionNetworks()(visual_scene)
tag = build_tag(visual_conv)
visual_conv = Concatenate()([tag, visual_conv])
visual_RN = RelationNetworks(visual_conv)
visual_out = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(visual_RN)
VisualModel = Model(inputs=[tag,visual_scene], outputs=visual_out)
print("model made")
# plot_model(VisualModel, to_file='/home/aakash/Relation_Network/figures/VisualModel1.png')

################################ Create parallel model ###############

# This executes Data Parallelism. Batch is divided equally on all GPUs for computation

try:
    parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(VisualModel, cpu_merge=True, cpu_relocation=True,gpus=2)
    print("Training using multiple GPUs..")
except:
    parallel_model = model
    print("Training using single GPU or CPU..")



################################# Training #################################################################################
workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1
batchsize=32
IMG_SIZE=100
train_df_path="/home/aakash/Relation_Network/training_df.pkl"
valid_df_path="/home/aakash/Relation_Network/validation_df.pkl"
image_dir="/home/aakash/Relation_Network/DL_Dataset"


from keras.optimizers import Adam
lr = 1e-4
adam = Adam(lr=lr)
parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])



#Save architecture
NAME = "2_conv_model"

with open(NAME+".json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(VisualModel.to_json())
print("model architecture saved as json file")



#create callbacks
# NAME = "{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))


checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(log_dir+'/'+NAME+'.h5', monitor='val_loss',verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)

csv_logger = keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(log_dir+"/"+NAME+".csv", separator=',', append=False)

tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=tensorboard_logsdir+'/'+NAME, histogram_freq=0, batch_size=batchsize, write_graph=True, write_grads=False, write_images=False, embeddings_freq=0, 
                      embeddings_layer_names=None, embeddings_metadata=None, embeddings_data=None, update_freq='epoch')





training_df=pd.read_pickle(train_df_path)
validation_df=pd.read_pickle(valid_df_path)


datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=training_df, directory=image_dir, 
                                            x_col="image", y_col="lesion", class_mode="categorical", 
                                            target_size=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE), batch_size=batchsize,shuffle=True)

validation_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=validation_df, directory=image_dir, 
                                            x_col="image", y_col="lesion", class_mode="categorical", 
                                            target_size=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE), batch_size=batchsize)



parallel_model.fit_generator(generator = train_generator,
                             steps_per_epoch = (training_df.shape[0])//batchsize,
                             validation_data = validation_generator,
                             validation_steps = (validation_df.shape[0])//batchsize,
                             epochs = 30,verbose=1,callbacks=[checkpoint, csv_logger,tensorboard],
                            use_multiprocessing=True,workers=workers)
```

`build_tag` function returns an input layer with a tensor (this is my second input).

But when I run this code, it shows the following error

!(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gGjoO89zwRw_zUQ14sUIrdC7oRKrdVT1/view?usp=sharing)

I made the `build_tag` function a Lambda layer and the value returned by `build_tag` is just value "tag" and NOT an input layer and remove "tag" input to the model and it starts to work.

This is the model-architecture  [before](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HlrWTVe6lNCawsZAtWKim258K2iRtOjQ/view?usp=sharing) converting the `build_tag` into Lambda layer and this one is [after](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dbQtZM0DJFu4JnM2xZ15TDOltcX2WU-b/view?usp=sharing) conversion.

Comment: How do you define `training_df`?

Comment: @keineahnung2345 Its a dataframe with 2 columns (one with image name and other with labels). I read a pickle file for it. And the code is working fine when `build_tag` is made into lambda layer but it takes too much time for the first epoch to start

Comment: Can you paste the full code here? So one can debug for you.

Comment: @keineahnung2345 Sure, let me put the code

Comment: @keineahnung2345 I have put the whole code. The dataset is of **Tif** format of only **90mb** . And it takes a lot of time to start the first epoch depending on the output of the `ConvolutionNetwork`

Comment: Can you also provide your dataset? Thanks.

Comment: @keineahnung2345 I am so sorry man. Its a proprietary dataset